# Converting between bases in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to learn Ruby using problems from this [subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer). I'm working on [a problem](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/2ao99p/7142014_challenge_171_easy_hex_to_8x8_bitmap/) that's asking me to take a string containing a series of hex values separated by spaces, then convert them to binary and do some work based on the binary values. I have what looks like should be a working solution, but I'm getting errors when I run it. Here's the code:

```
print "enter: "

vals = gets.chomp.split

for i in 0...vals.length do
   vals[i].hex.to_s(2)!
end

vals.each {|x| puts x}
```

I'm getting the following error messages:

```
test.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting keyword_end
test.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

From what I understand, the .hex method should return the decimal value of a hex string, and to_s(2)! should convert that integer to a binary string. Obviously, though, I'm not getting something.

Comment: the bang after `to_s` is not valid. and there is no `.to_s!` method

Comment: Who told you to use `!` here `vals[i].hex.to_s(2)!` ? Which doc are you following ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit - no one told me that; it was mostly the product of trial and error. I see why it was wrong, now.

Answer (score 2):

The bang after `to_s` is not a valid syntax on ruby. What you can have is a method ending with `!`, for example, `chomp!`. And there is no `.to_s!` method.

What you are looking for can be achieved by the following code:

```
print "enter: "

vals = gets.chomp.split

for i in 0...vals.length do
     vals[i] = vals[i].hex.to_s(2)
end

vals.each {|x| puts x}
```

Comment: Ben, fotanus undoubtedly thought it best to give you an answer that is as close as possible to the code you wrote, but you should be aware that it would be more Ruby-like to replace your `for..end` block with `vals.map! { |v| v.hex.to_s(2) }`. A detail: you don't need `chomp`; `gets.split` is sufficient.